# Simple structure initialization in Swift (4)?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, initialization

I'm new to Swift and trying to port some code.  I have this from an old project:

```
typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Normal[3];
    float TexCoord[2]; // New
} iconVertex;

const iconVertex iconVertices[] = {
    {{0.0,0.0, 0.0}, {0, 0, 1.0}, {0, 0}},
    {{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {0, 0, 1.0}, {1, 0}},
    {{0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, {0, 0, 1.0}, {0, 1}},
    {{1.0,  1.0, 0.0}, {0, 0, 1.0}, {1, 1}},
};
```

Is there any way to do that same array initialization in Swift?
Thanks!

Comment: why does this have a negative four score

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift you can use Structs to define your objects and create an init method that receives the parameters that you need to initialise.

```
struct IconVertex {
    var position: [Double]
    var normal: [Double]
    var textCoord: [Double]

    init(position: [Double], normal: [Double], textCoord: [Double]) {
        self.position = position
        self.normal = normal
        self.textCoord = textCoord
    }
}

let iconVertices: [IconVertex] = [
IconVertex(position: [0.0,0.0, 0.0], normal: [0, 0, 1.0], textCoord: [0, 0]),
IconVertex(position: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], normal: [0, 0, 1.0], textCoord: [1, 0]),
IconVertex(position: [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], normal: [0, 0, 1.0], textCoord: [0, 1]),
IconVertex(position: [1.0,  1.0, 0.0], normal: [0, 0, 1.0], textCoord: [1, 1])]
```

Comment: You don't need the `init`. With a `struct` you automatically get such an `init` if you don't provide any others.

Comment: Good point! But since he is porting some code I thought it was useful to show how you create an `init` too

Comment: Probably want to use `Vector3D` or tuple instead of array for the property types.